# PHP static variable not working

Tags: php, ajax, indexing, static

In my file adapter.php I have following code:

case 'buyCard':

```
        static $order=array();
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
        $price=$_POST['price']; //var_dump($price);
        $order['id']=$id; $order['quantity']=$quantity; $order['price']=$price;

        static $i=0;

        $_SESSION[$i]=$order; $i++; var_dump($i);

        break;
```

where informations like id, price and quantity comes from ajax placed in card.php file and it's activated 'onclick'. I need a counter, which will help me to store data in session every time user click on button that trigers this event. But my counter 'static $i' that is supposed to work as index is not incrementing, and I have no idea why? And if there is some other solution to this problem I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: I just tested your script, and your `static $i` is incrementing for me.

Comment: Because on every request `static $i` created again?

Comment: Nope, I created it global too, but it's always 1...

Comment: Since you said that "informations (...) come from Ajax", isn't it that you have a distinct new invokation of `buyCard.php` for each order? If so, it's normal that `static` has no effect!

Comment: Do you understand what is `request`?

Comment: Is the script you posted in some form of loop? Do you want your `static $i` to be incremented globally? Aren't you better off with `$_SESSION['i']`?

Comment: Does JavaScript have any way to declare static variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're invoking `buyCard.php` each time a new order is put, then `static` is of no help: it keeps updating its contained information *only during the same script instance*!

So you should instead use a session variable to work with your counter, like you're already doing for orders (but you'd better to have a distinct `orders` session variable rather than the counter).
Something like this:

```
session_start();
// ...
$order['id']=$_POST['id'];
$order['quantity']=$_POST['quantity'];
$order['price']=$_POST['price'];

@$_SESSION['orders_count']++;
$_SESSION['orders'][$_SESSION['orders_count']]=$order;
```

Note the `@` which avoids initiating `$_SESSION['orders_count']`: here this unloved error suppressor makes sense, since the only possible "error" is that the variable doesn't exist yet.